# node.js чтение и запись в 1 файл

Tags: node.js

Подскажите пожалуйста по решению задачки.

Читаем из file.txt побитово, делаем какие-то манипуляции, получившиеся данные (например все строки в теперь в верхнем регистре) записываем в тот же  file.txt перезаписывая его полностью.

У меня получается записать только в другой файл file2.txt. file.txt полностью стирается.

Текущий код:

```js
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');

const rs = fs.createReadStream('./file.txt', { highWaterMark: 1 }, 'utf8');
const ws = fs.createWriteStream('./file.txt', 'utf8');

let buf = '';
let dd = '';
rs.on('data', d => {
 // выражение
  dd += d;
  console.log(`Читаем ${d.length} байт`);
});
rs.on('end',() => {
  console.log('Прочитано из файла ' + dd);
  console.log('Записываем в файл результат ' + buf);
  console.error('Запись выполнена успешно.');
  ws.write(String(buf));
});
```

Comment: хочу увидеть "побитовое" чтение

Comment: подозреваю, fs.createWriteStream уже очищает файл, поэтому читать нечего. выполняйте эту строку уже когда чтение файла завершено, т.е. непосредственно перед write

Comment: Спасибо большое! Решено!